# Facebook profile picture is not loading in my app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have implemented Facebook SDK and Firebase implementations. I am trying to display name, email, and profile picture of the user who signs in with Facebook. Name and email are getting loaded but the profile picture is not getting loaded.

Here is the code:

Kotlin Code

```
auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val currentuser = auth.currentUser
        email.text=currentuser?.email
        val photourl = currentuser?.photoUrl.toString()
        Log.d("url","URL of profile image is $photourl")
        Glide.with(this).load(currentuser?.photoUrl.toString()).into(profile_image)
```

The XML Code

```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/profile_image"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

I am also attaching an image of the Activity:
[image: Dashboard Activity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting the correct image URL because of the following line of code:

```
val photourl = currentuser?.photoUrl.toString()
```

And this is happening because you are trying to get the URL from the FirebaseUser object. When you authenticate your users with Facebook, the `photoUrl` field inside the `currentuser` object is not populated. To be able to actually get that URL, you need to use the following lines of code:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.currentUser?.apply {
    for (userInfo in providerData) {
        if (userInfo.providerId == "facebook.com") {
            val photoUrl = userInfo.photoUrl
            Log.d("TAG", photoUrl.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

So you have to get the URL from the [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) object and not from the FirebaseUser object.

Comment: Still I am not getting the profile url. I am getting this url https://graph.facebook.com/1984789791730323/picture

Comment: That most likely means that the user has no image already set in his/her Facebook account. Can you show us the Facebook account where the profile pictures exist?

Comment: Sure, check out my profile https://www.facebook.com/Ishan301/

Comment: If you try to use `Log.d("TAG", userInfo.getUid())`, do you get the correct ID of the authenticated user? Is that happening as well for `userInfo.getDisplayName()`?

Comment: Yes the name and email being displayed are correct

Comment: There's one more thing I would like to add. This app is still in development mode and I have not made it go live. Do you it has anything to do with it?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. What does `Log.d("TAG", photoUrl.toString())` print in the logcat?

Comment: D/TAG: https://graph.facebook.com/1984789791730323/picture  this is what it shows

Comment: E/com.facebook.GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '922217168403499' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
these are the last two lines I am getting in run section

Comment: So if `userInfo.photoUrl` doesn't return the correct profile picture, then most likely you don't have permission for that. You should read again the docs. If you get permissions, you'll be able to display the picture using the code in my answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: yeah I was not having permissions. Thanks Alex!

Comment: So have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I did something else but it worked out fine . I just did Google sign in instead of Facebook sign-in

Comment: The code in my answer will work as well in the case of Google, using `userInfo.providerId == "google.com"`.

Comment: I have check marked your answer 

Comment: @AlexMamo getting same error now, used the same code, but getting default picture only, Raised question few days back but got no answer, please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77725863/not-able-to-fetch-facebook-profile-image-using-firebase-authentication

Answer (score 0):

**Use FirebaseUser Object**

```
private FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
user = auth.getCurrentUser();
```

*Now Call - user.getPhotoUrl()*

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).into(userImage);
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. Its just that you have used java and I have used kotlin