# Not able to fetch Facebook profile image using Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am working on a project in which I have integrated Facebook login using Firebase authentication. I am fetching the public profile picture. However my code is not able to do this task. Please try to fix this.

Here is the small part of the code I used

```
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    val photoUrl = "${user.photoUrl}?access_token=${token.token}"
```

Here I get not image

```
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    val photoUrl = user.photoUrl.toString()
```

When I used the following code, I am getting the default Facebook profile photo: [image: image which is shown]

Note: In XML file I am using the default Image View, not Facebook profile view attribute

Comment: What is the value of `user.photoUrl` that you are getting?  What are the properties of `user` that you are getting?

Comment: I am getting this url on using the second code https://graph.facebook.com/2148630908807216/picture, that is the firebase user object

Answer (score 0):

```
user?.let {
                        val facebookUserId = it.providerData[1].uid
                        val photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebookUserId/picture?type=large"

                }
```

Comment: Not working, getting default Facebook profile photo as I shared in the post, not the actual one, This code is equivalent to photoUrl = user.photoUrl.toString()